# EditorForModel/DisplayForModel Rendering Nothing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I have a very basic problem in MVC 4.  I am trying to use the "EditorForModel" to render a simple form, but the HTML is always blank (no Exception, nothing).

ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectViewModel {
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public bool Secured { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult New() {
   return View(new ProjectViewModel());
}
```

View:

```
@model BuMan.ViewModels.ProjectViewModel
@{ Html.EditorForModel();}
```

I am obviously missing something very obvious, but shouldn't that render some default inputs for each property?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove curlybraces around `Html.EditorForModel.`

Your view should be

```
@model BuMan.ViewModels.ProjectViewModel
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Comment: Wow, that was all it was.  Wasted hour that was!